# Does order matter in set intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to prove the following: $$A\setminus(B\cup C)=(A\setminus B)\cap(A\setminus C)$$

To do so, I must show that all the elements on the left-hand side exist on the right-hand side and vice versa. That is, $$\forall x\in A\setminus(B\cup C),\, x\in(A\setminus B)\cap(A\setminus C),$$ and, $$\forall x\in(A\setminus B)\cap(A\setminus C),\, x\in A\setminus(B\cup C).$$

I attempted to prove the former first. Let $x\in A\setminus(B\cup C)$. Therefore, $x\in A\cap(B\cup C)'$. By De Morgan's laws, this equates to $A\cap(B'\cap C')$. At this point, I am tempted to do the following. Given that $A\cap A=A$, I would like to rewrite $A\cap(B'\cap C')$ as $A\cap A\cap B'\cap C'$, then rearrange this expression into $A\cap B'\cap A\cap C'$, such that $x\in (A\setminus B)\cap(A\setminus C)$. I am not sure however, if $A\cap A\cap B'\cap C$ is equivalent to $A\cap B'\cap A\cap C'$. Hence the question:

> Does order matter in the intersection of sets? Does $A\cap B\cap C=C\cap A\cap B=B\cap A\cap C$, and so on?

Comment: Intersection $\cap$ is both associative and commutative, so your operations are allowed

Comment: Consider  for statements $P,Q,R,$ that the assertion  "$(P\land  Q \land R)$ is true" is equivalent to the assertion "$P$ is true and $Q$ is true and $R$ is true" and that, in this latter assertion, $P,Q,R$ can be equivalently re-arranged in any order.... Consider letting $P$ be $ x\in A ,$  letting $Q$ be $x\in B,$ letting $R$ be  $x\in C$. And   consider that then the definition of  $x\in A\cap B\cap C$ is just $(P\land Q\land R).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, order does not matter. This can be proven by proving that
$$A\cap B=B\cap A$$
Which is rather trivial, since
$$A\cap B=\{x|x\in A \land x\in B\}$$
$$B\cap A=\{x|x\in B \land x\in A\}$$
and since "and" is commutative, that is, if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are statements,
$$S_1 \land S_2\iff S_2\land S_1$$
You can say that
$$A\cap B=\{x|x\in A \land x\in B\}=\{x|x\in B \land x\in A\}=B\cap A$$
Which proves commutativity. Associativity can be proven similarly.

Comment: Also, $\cap$ is distributive over $\cap.$ As in the Q: $A\cap (B'\cap C')=(A\cap B')\cap (A\cap C').$